# Multiply column A values to Column B values and result in column C using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns A and B. Range of A is A1:A6 and B is B1:B6. Now, I want to multiply these two columns and display result in column C using excel VBA. For example

### A  B  C

### 2  3  6 (It is A1*B1)

### 3  8  24

### 9  2  18

### 7  3  21

### 2  4  8

### 5  4  20

I have tried this code but did not find it helpful:

```
Range("C1:C6").Value = Range("A1:A6") * Range("B1:B6")
```

Please guide me here as I am new to VBA. You help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
for i = 1 to 6
  cells(i,3) = cells(i,1) * cells(i,2)
next i
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but a bit more advanced. I have dynamic columns and ranges. Have created arrays in VBA, populated them with `rng.rows.count` and `rng.columns.count` and do know that a loop inside a loop should be used but not sure how to implement this cross-multiplication of columns in each row...

Comment: Sounds like you may want to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it. But if you still do then simply ask :)

```
'~~> This will enter the formula in the entire range in one go
Range("C1:C6").Formula = "=A1*B1"
'~~> This will convert the formula to values
Range("C1:C6").Value = Range("C1:C6").Value
```